# PHAsset video get exifInfo (metadata)

Tags: ios, ios7, phasset, photokit, phassetcollection

I want to get Exif information for a video file.

Below is the code to get Exif for image but it doesn't seems to work for videos.

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:photoAsset
                                              options:reqOptions
                                        resultHandler:
     ^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
         CIImage* ciImage = [CIImage imageWithData:imageData];
         DLog(@"Metadata : %@", ciImage.properties);
     }];
```

Is there any way to get the exif without writing the file into disk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get metadata for video file 
use below API where the information is in AVAsset object.

```
    - (PHImageRequestID)requestAVAssetForVideo:(PHAsset *)asset options:(nullable PHVideoRequestOptions *)options 
                resultHandler:(void (^)(AVAsset *__nullable asset, AVAudioMix *__nullable audioMix, NSDictionary *__nullable info))resultHandler;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check for the [documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phimagemanager?language=objc)

You can get the information for the video:

```
 - (PHImageRequestID)requestPlayerItemForVideo:(PHAsset *)asset 
                                  options:(PHVideoRequestOptions *)options 
                            resultHandler:(void (^)(AVPlayerItem *playerItem, NSDictionary *info))resultHandler;
```

Try using Utility for metadata: https://github.com/zakkhoyt/PHAsset-Utility

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The ExifInfo is present in playerItem ?  . As I cannot find much information in Info Dictionary

Comment: There's a helper utility, you can have the metadata using it: https://github.com/zakkhoyt/PHAsset-Utility

Comment: The helper utility method requestMetadataWithCompletionBlock doesn't work for vidoes